# How do I run multiple instances of an Ember app on the same page?

Tags: ember.js

I have a large ember application (survey system for scientists) that currently runs by itself 'full page'.

I'd like to now embed multiple copies of my ember app on an existing page (different surveys inline with a message board). Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/ that is the basically you put it in a div and initialize the Application with the right info.

Comment: @MatthewClark always check the version link, http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/

Comment: This seems more relevant to running two different applications on the same page.... I want to run run multiple instances of the SAME application. I could make a factory createCopyOfApp() method, but I'd rather not duplicate every class/method twice in memory?